# How to validate tensorflow-lite model converted from keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I am new Machine Learning. I tried this code to change my trained model from keras to tensorflow-lite:

```
# Converting a SavedModel to a TensorFlow Lite model. 
saved_model_dir = r'C:\Users\Munib\New folder\my_model.h5' 
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(saved_model_dir)
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(loaded_model)# .from_saved_model(saved_model_dir) 
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("my_model_converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Now, i want to validate my model which is made from conversion to check its working correctly or not so that i can than further use it in android studio for my project. Can someone tell me how to validate the `my_model_converted_model.tflite`.

Comment: What sort of input does this model take? Is it a simple array of floats or a multidimension array? You can always load it correctly inside android, and pass as input the same array as when you pass it on computer. The result should be the same. You can also check documentation with code samples for Java and Python inference [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference)

Comment: Sir, i trained my model on two classes of trees. Now i don't know how to validate in tensorflowlite

Comment: Check the inference with Python API [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_python). Compare the result with the one from Keras model.

Comment: Sir, i'm bit confuse. i tried it but i don't know how to send my test image in it

Comment: I understand that it may be difficult...but for that purpose you have to make a python notebook for me to check. Do you use colaboratory?

Comment: @Farmaker Thank you. No Sir, I made this code on my computer. Sir, if you have linkdin id i can send you the problem there i am having so you can help me

Comment: check your linkedin account..or send to farmaker47@gmail.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215976/discussion-between-mirza-munib-and-farmaker).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Keras model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as K
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K, models
from tensorflow.keras.models import *
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *

# load model from saved chackpoint
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('my_model.h5')

# print model layers and input/outputs
print(model.layers)
for input in model.inputs:
  print(input)
for node in model.outputs:
  print(node)

# Load and transform image
image_a = plt.imread('1017_1.jpg')
image_a = cv2.resize(image_a,(150,150))
image_a = np.asarray(image_a)/255
image_a = np.reshape(image_a,(1,150,150,3))

# view output
model.predict(image_a)
# array([[0.6071461]], dtype=float32)
```

For Tensorflow-Lite:

```
# generate .tflite file
tflite_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('my_model.h5')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(tflite_model)
tflite_save = converter.convert()
open("my_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_save)    

# Load the TFLite model and allocate tensors. View details
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="my_model.tflite")
print(interpreter.get_input_details())
print(interpreter.get_output_details())
print(interpreter.get_tensor_details())
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

# Test the model on input data.
input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
print(input_shape)

# Use same image as Keras model
input_data = np.array(image_a, dtype=np.float32)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

interpreter.invoke()

# The function `get_tensor()` returns a copy of the tensor data.
# Use `tensor()` in order to get a pointer to the tensor.
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
print(output_data)
# [  1 150 150   3]
# [[0.6071461]]
```

All the above with:

```
print(tf.__version__)
print(K.__version__)
2.2.0
2.3.0-tf
```

I hope I helped!

Answer (score 1):

You could defined `Interpreter`, `allocate_tensors` and `invoke` to get the output from the tflite and compare it with the results from Keras as shown below.

```
import numpy as np
# Run the model with TensorFlow to get expected results.
TEST_CASES = 10

# Run the model with TensorFlow Lite
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_content=tflite_model)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

for i in range(TEST_CASES):
  expected = model.predict(x_test[i:i+1])
  interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]["index"], x_test[i:i+1, :, :])
  interpreter.invoke()
  result = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]["index"])

  # Assert if the result of TFLite model is consistent with the TF model.
  np.testing.assert_almost_equal(expected, result,decimal=6)
  print("Done. The result of TensorFlow matches the result of TensorFlow Lite.")
```

Full example code is [here](https://github.com/jvishnuvardhan/Stackoverflow_Questions/blob/master/tflite_simple_floatmodel_inference.ipynb). The code I used is from this TensorFlow [resource](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/experimental_new_converter/Keras_LSTM_fusion_Codelab.ipynb).

Comment: Thank you sir, what should i change in the code as i have to pic a image from the computer and then test it with the trained model?

Comment: Hello Sir, it gives error on this line: ```expected = model.predict(x_test[i:i+1])``` The error is: ```NameError: name 'model' is not defined```

Comment: Change "model" to "loaded_model"

Comment: Sir how i load the model as i am not using keras model now i am validating tensorflow-lite model

Comment: interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_content=tflite_model) should work if you have used my code. You could change argument to model_path or model_dir.